# sql counts wrong number of likes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written an sql statement that besides all the other columns should return the number of comments and the number of likes of a certain post. It works perfectly when I don't try to get the number of times it has been shared too. When I try to get the number of time it was shared instead it returns a wrong number of like that seems to be either the number of shares and likes or something like that. Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    [...], 
    count(CS.commentId) as shares, 
    count(CL.commentId) as numberOfLikes
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM accountSpecifics 
     WHERE institutionId= '{$keyword['id']}') `AS`
INNER JOIN 
    account A ON A.id = `AS`.accountId
INNER JOIN 
    comment C ON C.accountId = A.id 
LEFT JOIN 
    commentLikes  CL ON C.commentId = CL.commentId
LEFT JOIN 
    commentShares  CS ON C.commentId = CS.commentId
GROUP BY 
    C.time
ORDER BY 
    year, month, hour, month
```

Could you also tell me if you think this is an efficient SQL statement or if you would do it differently? thank you!

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Don't use reserved words (`as`) for table aliases.

Comment: well I am using ` to make it literal. Anyway mysql

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

```
SELECT 
    [...], 
    count(DISTINCT CS.commentId) as shares, 
    count(DISTINCT CL.commentId) as numberOfLikes
```

Better approach:

```
SELECT [...]
     , Coalesce(shares.numberOfShares, 0) As numberOfShares
     , Coalesce(likes.numberOfLikes  , 0) As numberOfLikes
FROM   [...]
 LEFT
  JOIN (
        SELECT commentId
             , Count(*) As numberOfShares
        FROM   commentShares  
        GROUP
            BY commentId
       ) As shares
    ON shares.commentId = c.commentId
 LEFT
  JOIN (
        SELECT commentId
             , Count(*) As numberOfLikes
        FROM   commentLikes
        GROUP
            BY commentId
       ) As likes
    ON likes.commentId = c.commentId
```

Comment: Thanks!...I had to change commentId to accountId too though otherwise the count would always be 1 or 0.

Comment: The first query is still wrong. You would have to count the distinct IDs of the tables in question. I.e. `count(DISTINCT CS.CommentSharesId) as shares` and `count(DISTINCT CL.CommentLikesId) as NumberOfLikes`. And I like your second query, but you forgot the column aliases for `Count(*)`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner that's what my first query always said... cheers for the alias bit. Fixeded!

Comment: I think your first query was right except for the fact that it was counting distinct commentId which would be the same for all likes but as I said if you count distinct accountid then it seems to be working.. i am not sure about the second one you posted but I will try it as soon as i go back home.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
SELECT 
[...], 
(select count(*) from commentLikes CL where C.commentId = CL.commentId) as shares, 
(select count(*) from commentShares CS where C.commentId = CS.commentId) as numberOfLikes
FROM 
(SELECT * 
 FROM accountSpecifics 
 WHERE institutionId= '{$keyword['id']}') `AS`
INNER JOIN account A ON A.id = `AS`.accountId
INNER JOIN comment C ON C.accountId = A.id 
GROUP BY C.time
ORDER BY year, month, hour, month
```

If you use JOINs, you're getting back one result set, and COUNT(any field) simply counts the rows and will always compute the same thing, and in this case the wrong thing. Subqueries are what you need here. Good luck!

EDIT: as posted below, count(distinct *something*) can also work, but it's making the database do more work than necessary for the answer you want to end up with.

Comment: This works too. So basically i have to compute those separately otherwise it is going to count all the comments Ids instead of just the one in the commentslike column